# FU fails to upload chunked files in version 4 signing

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, fine-uploader

I have successfully upgraded to FU version 5.41 and thought I had it nailed. I was and continue to be able to upload to Frankfurt. Only thing, i was using 1MB files,  then when I tried a larger one, it failed with the error "Problem initiating upload request."
I can confirm that keeping all things the same if I pass a version 2 signature on chuncked files it will upload properly but change to version 4 and it does not. Yes, I did this example on a S3 that supports both version 2 and version 4. ( else it wouldn't be a point proven)

I am using S3 upload with php server side. 
I am passing the correct region, version number and expected buckets etc as well as chun.

In the PHP example code I noticed the expected s3 host name, which I couldn't see as a requirement in the changelog documentation what you need to do to support version 4 signatures, regardless I added this anyway...  just to be sure what this is? It is for example bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com is that correct?

Any ideas, where I am going wrong, thanks
Any extra info you might need from me? Below is copied from the http request that is failing, I hope it is what you want

```
Request URL:https://videodesktv-ingest-syd.s3.amazonaws.com/console/2_mumford_lover_of_the_light.mp4?uploads
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:54.231.252.151:443
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Mon, 14 Dec 2015 04:29:06 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
x-amz-id-2:0dkXc0/yOnzrI6T9cClx6R6SQI8ixfs99rS5zX0nuCorHyVNh7CEWzbuNnay5KEmhQD1816MdRQ=
x-amz-request-id:D4EDCC40832B34AC
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type, x-amz-acl, x-amz-content-sha256, x-amz-date, x-amz-meta-qqfilename
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:videodesktv-ingest-syd.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin:https://videodesk.tv
Referer:https://videodesk.tv/1/console
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Which specific request is failing?

Comment: I'm asking specifically about http requests. Which one is failing? Is it the request to your signature server, the POST to S3, or the first PUT to S3? For the failing request, what is the response status and body?

Comment: Not clear on the current issue...

Comment: It would be best if you edit your answer to include information regarding the exact failing HTTP request, along with that request's status code and response payload. Also, if the issue appears to be with signing the request, then please include the header information from the example PHP file that you adjusted to suit your environment.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTTP request details posted in your question, an OPTIONS request is failing to your S3 bucket. In the context of CORS, this is called the "preflight" request, sent by the browser as a safety check before sending the underlying request (in this case, the first request in a series of requests needed to upload a file in chunks to S3).

The response to this preflight is 403, which indicates that your S3 bucket does not have proper CORS configuration. Pay close attention to the following headers in the preflight request:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type, x-amz-acl, x-amz-content-sha256, x-amz-date, x-amz-meta-qqfilename

Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
```

Your bucket's CORS settings must be configured to accept the POST method and the headers listed in the "Access-Control-Request-Headers" header.

Also, be sure the origin of "https://videodesk.tv" is listed as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out clearly, it is working now. I was missing the NEW header for version 4 signatures listed as x-amz-content-sha256 - this is why version 2 requests were working. May I suggest adding this to the documentation changelog instructions ads it is not mentioned and was absolutely required.

Comment: I just updated the [S3 server-side doc](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html) to include this header in the CORS section.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to users existing CORS configuration please note you need to add x-amz-content-sha256

Comment: I would also like to ask why in your PHP example this is mentioned when it seems to not be required, as long as expected bucket is correct...... $expectedHostName = $_ENV['S3_HOST_NAME']; // v4-only

Comment: [It _is_ needed for v4](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-s3-server/blob/master/endpoint.php#L141).